# Getting length of a float(Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

How can I get the length in integers of a number? In this case, I'm using it in a while loop. So, how can I get something to de something while the length of a float?

Comment: The downvotes are because what you are asking doesn't make sense without clarification;  the "length of a variable" can mean many things, but few of them are ever questions you might need to ask.

Comment: @bbum Why thank you for the point, I'll try to make my questions clearer (even thought I didn't understand that with "but few of them are ever questions you might need to ask."......)

Comment: It is rare in Objective-C to need to know the length of a variable in terms of # of bytes.  Raw encoding/decoding of data is generally not needed as their are higher level APIs that do that for you.  Hence the comment.

Comment: @bbum I have still only started with Objective-C, so I'm learning..... But thanx for pointing it out anyways

Comment: Certainly;   we all started somewhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sizeof()`:

```
float f = 123.0f;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(f); i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Or perhaps you meant the length of the value within the variable?

```
float f = 123.0f;
for (float i = 0.0f; i < f; i += 1.0f)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: O.O I'm confused!! I tried it before, and it didn't work, I tried it now and it worked!!! Thanks!